# ReactJS - Current values in fields disappear after setting form to not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-river-yeiej?file=/src/TextForm.js

I have a simple form that lifts state upward to update it's parent state. This form can be hidden by setting a state `formVisible` to false.

I noticed that when I update my word via the form submit, the value in the field remains. Eg, if I enter "haha" and press submit, the "haha" value remains in the field.

However, when I set formVisible to false, then set to true again, I notice that the value in the field disappears.

I want to make the field still show my old value after I hide and unhide the form.

One solution I've tried is to use `defaultValue` in my input field, and pass the old state into it. But I ran into a problem: If I update a word, hide the form, then unhide the form, and submit the form again, no word will be displayed (because the `enteredValue` state is still blank). I want the form to still be able to update.

What's a good way I can address this?

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import TextForm from "./TextForm";

export default function App() {
  const [myWord, setMyWord] = useState("default");
  const [formVisible, setFormVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleUpdateWord = (word) => {
    setMyWord(word);
  };

  const showForm = () => {
    setFormVisible(true);
  };

  const hideForm = () => {
    setFormVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {myWord}
      {formVisible && (
        <TextForm handleUpdateWord={handleUpdateWord} word={myWord} />
      )}
      <button onClick={showForm}>Show the form </button>
      <button onClick={hideForm}>Hide the form </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TextForm.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const TextForm = (props) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState();

  const valueChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setEnteredValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.handleUpdateWord(enteredValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={valueChangeHandler}
          defaultValue={props.word}
        />
        <button type="submit">Update word! </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextForm;
```

Comment: Just set your initial state for `enteredValue` to be `word` and should be good

Answer (score 1):

When user clicks on hide the form without submitting the entered value is lost as the TextForm component unmounts, so one solution for this is to preserve the state of TextForm in the parent component, we can have 2 different states in parent Component, one is for SubmittedValue that will be displayed over the top, other state is for the EnteredValue of the TextForm component, in this way one can preserve non submitted values and those will persist even if the TextForm Component unmounts

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-cdn-bxxhg?file=/src/App.js

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import TextForm from "./TextForm";

export default function App() {
  const [myWord, setMyWord] = useState("default");
  const [enteredVal, setEnteredVal] = useState(myWord);
  const [formVisible, setFormVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleUpdateWord = (word) => {
    setMyWord(word);
  };

  const handleUpdateEnteredVal = (word) => {
    setEnteredVal(word);
  };

  const showForm = () => {
    setFormVisible(true);
  };

  const hideForm = () => {
    setFormVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {myWord}
      {formVisible && (
        <TextForm
          handleUpdateWord={handleUpdateWord}
          word={enteredVal}
          handleUpdateEnteredVal={handleUpdateEnteredVal}
        />
      )}
      <button onClick={showForm}>Show the form </button>
      <button onClick={hideForm}>Hide the form </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TextForm.js

```
  const TextForm = (props) => {
  const valueChangeHandler = (e) => {
    props.handleUpdateEnteredVal(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const submittedVal = e.target.elements["form-input"].value;
    props.handleUpdateWord(submittedVal);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input
          id="form-input"
          type="text"
          onChange={valueChangeHandler}
          defaultValue={props.word}
        />
        <button type="submit">Update word! </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be to not let the TextForm component unmount. Currently in your code when the form state changes the TextForm component unmounts because of which we lose our current input state. To fix that we can do the following:

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import TextForm from "./TextForm";

export default function App() {
  const [myWord, setMyWord] = useState("default");
  const [formVisible, setFormVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleUpdateWord = (word) => {
    setMyWord(word);
  };

  const toggleForm = () => {
    setFormVisible((prevValue) => !prevValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {myWord}
      <TextForm
        isFormVisible={formVisible}
        handleUpdateWord={handleUpdateWord}
        word={myWord}
      />
      <button onClick={toggleForm}>Toggle Form </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TextForm.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const TextForm = (props) => {
  const { isFormVisible } = props;
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState();

  const valueChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setEnteredValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.handleUpdateWord(enteredValue);
  };

  return (
    isFormVisible && (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={valueChangeHandler}
            defaultValue={enteredValue}
          />
          <button type="submit">Update word! </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export default TextForm;
```

*I have replaced the two buttons to toggle the form state with one single toggle button but that has no effect on anything that we are concerned with.*